# sql retrieve result of days between more then the set day value

Tags: sql

I have create a SQL table which contains stock,  category, start date and end date. I need to find the date difference between max date and min date which greater than 3 day. Below is my coding:

```
SELECT stock, category, MIN(start_date) || '..' || MAX(start_date) AS date_range,
     Trunc(MAX(actual_run_date) - MIN(actual_run_date)) AS days_between
FROM  schedule
left outer join astock
ON schedule.stock= astock.stock
WHERE (STATUS ='COMPLETED' OR STATUS IS NULL)
AND START_DATE>SYSDATE-15
GROUP BY stock,category
```

How should I edit my coding so that the result `days_between` display out only the result which more than 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `HAVING` clause, which is like `where` but after grouping.

```
SELECT stock, category, MIN(start_date) || '..' || MAX(start_date) AS date_range,
     Trunc(MAX(actual_run_date) - MIN(actual_run_date)) AS days_between
FROM  schedule
left outer join astock
ON schedule.stock= astock.stock
WHERE (STATUS ='COMPLETED' OR STATUS IS NULL)
AND START_DATE>SYSDATE-15
GROUP BY stock,category
HAVING Trunc(MAX(actual_run_date) - MIN(actual_run_date)) > 3
```

Some database engines will understand

```
HAVING days_between > 3
```

but as far as I know not all of them.